# How do I add jquery library to Netbeans 8.1 project

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, netbeans-8.1

I have installed the 'All' version of Netbeans 8.1 and have started a HTML5/Cordova project.

In the documentation there is a javascript step in the New Project wizard but in the Netbeans 8.1 wizard this step is missing.

I am a bit of a noob so please can someone answer how I add a jquery library to the project?

Thanks

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html

Comment: Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>` in your main file

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the responses, but after a bit of digging I found the solution.

Right click on the Project name in the tree view and click properties.

The Project Properties window pops up.

Go to CDNJS under JavaScript Libraries and click Add.

In the Add CNDJS Library popup type the first couple of letters and it will display a bunch of libraries.

Pick the one you want and click Add Library.

[image: Two wizards to add libraries to Netbeans 8.1]

Comment: Hey Rob, looks like it took you about 3 days to get this one sorted out, so thank you for saving me the same 3 days!  I started looking into this one about a month ago, but only for a few minutes each time.  I'm so glad I luckily stumbled onto your answer this "few minutes".

Answer (score 1):

you can look at this [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html)

[image]

if you have more questions let me know .

Comment: Thanks, that works. I thought there might be a way to select the libraries when you create the project like in Netbeans 7.3 new project wizard, but if not this what I would call the usual way to do it.